# How to make a linux compatible dist from windows in play framework

Tags: deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to make a linux compatible dist from windows in play framework??
It generates .bat files but I want .sh files when I do $play dist

Answer (score 1):

If you check the play [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist) they said what happens with this file and what you need, also for [activator](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist)

> For Windows users a start script will be produced with a .bat file
>   extension. Use this file when running a Play application on Windows.
>
> ```
> For Unix users, zip files do not retain Unix file permissions so when the file is expanded the start script will be required to be set
>
> as an executable:
>
> $ chmod +x /path/to/bin/<project-name>
>
> Alternatively a tar.gz file can be produced instead. Tar files retain permissions. Invoke the universal:package-zip-tarball task
>
> instead of the dist task:
>
> play universal:package-zip-tarball
> ```

With activator, I suppose alse witout it, it generates a bat and file with helpers for shell scripts:

```
###  ------------------------------- ###
###  Helper methods for BASH scripts ###
###  ------------------------------- ###
```

Here you have a caprute the one without extension

[image: Activator output after dist command in Idea console]

Also in the doc you can use the native packager, which creates images for specific OS:

Play uses the SBT Native Packager plugin. The native packager plugin declares the dist task to create a zip file. Invoking the dist task is directly equivalent to invoking the following:

```
$ play universal:package-bin

Many other types of archive can be generated including:

    tar.gz
    OS X disk images
    Microsoft Installer (MSI)
    RPMs
    Debian files

Please consult the documentation on the native packager for more information.
```

Here is the [doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer..but what I am stuggling in is I have  awindows PC and I want to generate a package runnable on linux machine.
So only the native packager is left as an option I Guess and I being new to this..Its very confusing.
Also Is their any way to generate a war without the plugin??

Comment: You can check to buils a jar, first wich paly are you using and then check this Using the SBT assembly plugin, in the doc

Comment: I find the documentation a little bit confusing at this point: After I made the zip-file, the doc says `This produces a ZIP file containing all JAR files needed to run your application` (without using any further tools?). And for windows you have a .bat-file that you can simply start from the console. But when I try to run this on a linux machine, the documentation does not tell how to. 2 possibilities now: The sentence I quoted is wrong / incomplete, or the documentation does not show the command to start this under linux.

Comment: Just noticed: You simply need to type `./APPNAME` to start your app in linux. This info would be nice for an unexperienced user.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the zip file generated after running the `dist` task. `cd` into the bin directory and run `./appname`